# how to use sql like with case in mysql?

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to do a MySQL query as

```
SELECT distinct FROM_UNIXTIME(FLOOR(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(DateAndTime)/(60*2))*(60*2)) as DateAndTime,
       (CASE WHEN TagName like '%AHU-204\CV' THEN Val END) AS Tag0 
       from view1 
       where (view1.DateAndTime between "2014-12-03 11:30" AND "2014-12-03 13:00") 
       GROUP BY DateAndTime
```

It fetches `DateAndTime` column correctly but instead of fetching values from table it just displays `NULL` in `Tag0` column. There are values present in Val column of my view1.

Comment: Did you try with `group by 1` instead of `group by dateandtime`?

Comment: nope..i will try and let you know..

Comment: i tried..still displaying NULL

Comment: post some sample records for the said fields in the table.

Comment: when i write tanname like '%AHU_204%' it show a very first value from table but i want it to show value for ahu_204\cv.b'coz there are multiple cases i have o match

Comment: Your case selects Tag0 if TagName matches the matchstring, but, if the value on database doesn't match, it will select NULL as Tag0. Try adding an else to that case see if it returns the value on else (if so, then your matchstring might be broken (or the value on your DB simply don't match with it at all))

Comment: DateAndTime                  TagIndex        Val       TagName
2014-12-03 11:07:32           0               100      NEW_AHU\AHU_204\CV
2014-12-03 11:07:32           1               22.5    NEW_AHU\AHU_204\PV
2014-12-03 11:07:32           2               21.5     NEW_AHU\AHU_204\RH
2014-12-03 11:07:32           3                22       NEW_AHU\AHU_204\SP
2014-12-03 11:07:32           4                1 NEW_AHU\AHU_204\RUN_FB

Comment: thanks Felype..you are right..because i had tried it using else and it returns that else value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A case without else will post NULL value when none of its conditions matches, in your case, when TagName doesn't match the like command, it will post NULL to Tag0.

**Example 1:** *This posts null to tag0 when case doesn't match (original query)*

```
SELECT distinct FROM_UNIXTIME(FLOOR(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(DateAndTime)/(60*2))*(60*2)) as DateAndTime,
(CASE WHEN TagName like '%AHU-204\CV' THEN Val END) AS Tag0 from view1 
where (view1.DateAndTime between "2014-12-03 11:30" AND "2014-12-03 13:00") 
GROUP BY DateAndTime
```

If you need to collect only those values which match the like condition, then move that like condition to WHERE clause

**Example 2:** *Move that 'case' from select to the WHERE clause. When the condition doesn't match it will just not post to the result.*

```
SELECT distinct FROM_UNIXTIME(FLOOR(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(DateAndTime)/(60*2))*(60*2)) as DateAndTime, 
TagName AS Tag0 from view1 
where (view1.DateAndTime between "2014-12-03 11:30" AND "2014-12-03 13:00") AND UPPER(TagName) like UPPER('%AHU-204\CV') 
GROUP BY DateAndTime
```

*Note upper() on TagName and expression to enforce case-insensibility.*

If you need multiple matches, you can either set multiple cases on where clause:

**Example 3:** *Matching multiple patters using "OR" on WHERE clause*

```
SELECT distinct FROM_UNIXTIME(FLOOR(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(DateAndTime)/(60*2))*(60*2)) as DateAndTime,
TagName AS Tag0 from view1
where (view1.DateAndTime between "2014-12-03 11:30" AND "2014-12-03 13:00") AND 
(UPPER(TagName) like UPPER('%AHU-204\CV') OR UPPER(TagName) like UPPER('%CTH-506\ST%'))
GROUP BY DateAndTime
```

or add a WHERE Tag0 IS NOT NULL:

**Example 4:** *Using example 1 query and removing the results where Tag0 is null*

```
SELECT DateAndTime, Tag0 FROM (
    SELECT distinct FROM_UNIXTIME(FLOOR(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(DateAndTime)/(60*2))*(60*2)) as DateAndTime,
    (CASE WHEN UPPER(TagName) like '%AHU-204\CV' THEN Val END) AS Tag0 from view1 
    where (view1.DateAndTime between "2014-12-03 11:30" AND "2014-12-03 13:00")
    GROUP BY DateAndTime) AS Derived 
WHERE Tag0 IS NOT NULL;
```

Also just an addendum, if you're trying to match '%ahu-204\CV' with '%AHU-204\CV', you can get a case sensitivity issue depending on your charset.
In this case, try to match UPPER(TagName) like '%AHU-204\CV' and you'll get a case insensitive match.

Comment: @Felype..error:#1054 - Champ 'Tag0' inconnu dans where clause. for 4th query given by u.what does it mean?

Comment: @user1993 it says Tag0 doesnt exist, forgot we have to derive when using custom alias in Where clause, sorry. Updated

Comment: @user1993 updated. I extracted where tag0 is not null but, still had it in the inner query (thus the error would just be the same) Try once more now, should be working.

Comment: @Felype..Hi..thank you for your reply..I tried your updated query,It's returning an empty result set thought there are values present in my table here..column tag0 is not present in my view1 to fetch values from it .we are defining and creating it in query at run time..am I right?..plz help me

Comment: Yes, the inner query selects Tag0 as the expression you provide, the outer query selects that Tag0 as a column (considering the inner table as a derived table) and then checks if its null or not. I'd say a good way to test this is to run the inner query and see its results, If it returns a lot of nulls but the desired values in between then the problem is in the outer query, but I don't really think so. Tried using UPPER(TagName) instead? Most charsets will not match 'ahu' with 'AHU', for example, for case sensitiveness.

Comment: I tried ur updated query bt still its returning null.Here is my view1 from which we fetching cols for query- 'create view view1 as select floattable.DateAndTime,floattable.TagIndex,floattable.Val,tagtable.TagName from floattable inner join tagtable on floattable.TagIndex=tagtable.TagIndex;'. there are 141 tagindexes in tagtable and millions of records in floattable for each tagindex.so i wanted to fetch values according to tagnames selected from a dropdown and within a datetime interval entered by user and display result in table format

Comment: @user1993 Try moving the Tag match to where clause as exemplified in block of code #2

Comment: @Felype..I dident get you actually..can you provide me that with updated query.plz

Comment: @user1993 try Example 2.